# Why GCC does not evaluate constexpr at compile time?

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, constexpr

As an example:

```
class something {
public:
  static constexpr int seconds(int hour, int min, int sec)
  { return hour*3600+min*60+sec; }
}
```

then:

```
printf("Look at the time: %d\n", something::seconds(10, 0, 0));
```

Will compile to a call to the function using g++, instead of putting a constant number.
Why would g++ do that? There's no gain in it and kinda defeats the purpose of using constexpr instead of awful macros.

Comment: What optimization flags are you using?

Comment: @NeilButterworth surely the compiler can replace the something::seconds call with the result at compile time? What does that have to do with it being a parameter to a variadic function?

Comment: Can't reproduce. Give g++ version and optimization setting. As a matter of fact, even without constexpr any sane compiler would replace the call with a constant.

Comment: @NeilButterworth, what are you talking about? Of course it can!

Comment: To force constexpr evaluation, use `constexpr auto value = something::seconds(10, 0, 0));` then `printf("Look at the time: %d\n", value);`

Comment: @Jarod42, that would only force it in this particular context. Compilers would still be free to leave the function call in other contexts, but they don't do it in my experiments.

Comment: That has nothing to do with the actual value passed to the function. Only how printf gets its arguments.

Comment: @NeilButterworth, you are just wrong. Look at the assembly yoursef, there is no call with proper optimization settings.

Comment: @SergeyA  I was assuming the OP's post was correct in that the code compiled to a call.

Comment: @NeilButterworth, depends on optimization settings. However, you were arguing that it has something to do with variadic nature of prints, while it has nothing to do with it.

Comment: @Jarod42 You're right, it does work that way if I do that. I don't think it should, tho.
In fact, I'm stuck with compiling with an older GCC with -O0. Reading it was my understanding that it was ALWAYS evaluated at compile time where it made sense --and it's said to prefer that over #defines, which I was at the time slowly replacing by static constexpr int/uint/size_t.
Anyway, I'm still using it over defines for the type safety and readability even at a cost of lengthier binaries.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> Why would g++ do that?

`constexpr` functions only *must* be evaluated at compile time in situations where the result is used as a constant expression. These include things like initializing a `constexpr` variable and being used as a template argument.

In other situations, even when a `constexpr` function is invoked with arguments that are all themselves constant expressions, it is up to the implementation to do what it wants. Typically, it'll depend on the optimization flags. On both gcc 6.2 and clang 3.9.1, for instance, `-O0` will emit a call at runtime but `-O1` will emit the constant `36000`.

Comment: Godbolt (http://gcc.godbolt.org/) is your friend...  Sticking the above code into godbolt shows that in the above simple case, it does get compiled into a compile-time value of 36000.

Comment: @AndreKostur ... with `-O1` or higher, yes.